# Cross-platform authentication disparity with Google-Signin and React-Native

Tags: oauth, react-native, google-signin

I'm trying to implement backend authentication with a mobile app written in react-native. I managed to get it working with android but I got a problem with iOS.

With Android, the *webClientId* appears in the *aud* field in the generated token, which is the one that the backend checks. On iOS however it's the *iOSClientId*. So authentication on iOS fails.

**Configuration of the GoogleSignin module:**

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: [], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
    iosClientId: '817980298693-[...].apps.googleusercontent.com', // only for iOS
    webClientId: '181764353768-fdc[...].apps.googleusercontent.com', // client ID of type WEB for your server (needed to verify user ID and offline access)
});
```

**Content of the generated token on iOS (from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=):**

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "aud": "817980298693-[...].apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "azp": "817980298693-[...].apps.googleusercontent.com",
  [...]
}
```

**Content of the generated token on Android (from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=):**

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "aud": "181764353768-fdc[...].apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "azp": "181764353768-2rs[...].apps.googleusercontent.com",
  [...]
}
```

So my questions are:

- Is it normal that the webClientId appears nowhere in the generated token on iOS ?
- Should I just check both client ids in the backend or is there a way to have the same behavior on both platforms ?

Thanks for your help !